# Vim NERDTreeFilesysMenu: how to enable vim keybindings

Tags: vim, nerdtree

with the filesystem menu (default shortcut 'm') in the NERDTree plugin, you can easily add/copy/move/delete files and folders.

But the vim keybindings (h,j,k,l, w, e, b, y, v and so on) do not work in that menu.

I know there is a key-combo to enable those vim keybindings in that menu, but I have forgotten it and cannot find it again via google/forums... The shortcut is also not documented in the help menu.

**Does anyone know how to enable the vim keybindings in the NERDTree FileSystem Menu?**

This comes in very handy when creating large amount of files and folders with more or less the same name. I would like to copy/paste and use the vim movement keys (w, e, b, h,j,k,l) in that menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just found it myself while mashing random keys in the menu.

You can press ctrl+f in the menu, the menu will then change to another form(some sort of command history view ?!) where you can use the vim keybindings. When your input is done, press enter!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't find that shortcut in the plugin's documentation because that's built-in Vim functionality: `:help c_CTRL-F`! The plugin uses `input()` to query for the file name, CTRL-F will switch to Vim's command-line window, using the input line history.

You can use the same shortcut while typing an `:ex` command, or while `/search`ing!